# Mix install.archive fails and asks for -i to specify directory

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am running this command

```
$ mix archive.install github ninenines/cowboy
* Getting new package (https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy.git)
remote: Counting objects: 9525, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.        
remote: Total 9525 (delta 0), reused 11 (delta 0), pack-reused 9511        
...
** (Mix) Cannot create archive without input directory, please pass -i as an option
```

But there is no -i option, and mix won't let me do that.  How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** It’s impossible to execute this task outside of `mix` project.

From the [`Mix.Tasks.Archive.Install`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Archive.Install.html#content) documentation:

> If no argument is supplied but there is an archive in the project’s root directory (created with mix archive.build), then the archive will be installed locally. For example:
>
> ```
> mix do archive.build, archive.install
> ```
>
> If an argument is provided, it should be a local path or a URL to a prebuilt archive, a git repository, a github repository, or a hex package.

`mix archive.install` calls `archive.build` under the hood. The error you are receiving is introduced by [`archive.build`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/b873d7819836c2ee4340c6bf56fa3192ad59f141/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/archive.build.ex#L67), which, unlike `install`, [receives `-i` option](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Archive.Build.html#module-command-line-options).

It, in turn, expects the [installation spec](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.4/lib/mix/lib/mix/local/installer.ex#L63) to be present.

The summing up: one might provide the `dep_spec` as shown in the source linked above, but in general `mix` just does not understand where to *build* the downloaded packages. Afterward, it will nevertheless be in doubt, where to install it. So the simplest solution would be to create the empty project with `mix new` and then execute these tasks there.